# Is there a method to listen and detect installation and uninstallations?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-launcher

I'm trying to build a launcher in Android Studio and I am using a RecyclerView

You know, when an app is installed, it is automatically added to the launcher menu. Similarly, when an app is removed, it is removed from the view.

Which method should be used to make this happen? Now, list is updated every time the view is created:

```java
public ArrayList<AppInfo> getAppInfo(){
        ArrayList <AppInfo> appsList = new ArrayList<>();
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        List<ResolveInfo> allApps = pm.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
        for(ResolveInfo ri:allApps) {
            AppInfo app = new AppInfo();
            app.label = ri.loadLabel(pm);
            app.packageName = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
            app.icon = ri.activityInfo.loadIcon(pm);
            appsList.add(app);
            System.out.println(app.label);

        }
        return appsList;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.your.receiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
                    <data android:scheme="package"/> 
                </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
```

Comment: It says "permission is granted only to system apps".